# editing values in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Can someone please tell me how do I edit values from my winforms and save it in the database.

I have written this code but when I execute the code the slipNo value appears in the textbox but nothing edits or nothing happens:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=TANYA-PC;Initial Catalog=biore1;Integrated Security=True";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM cottonpurchase";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
da.Fill(ds, "cottonpurchase");
connection.Close();

// create the BindingSource
BindingSource bsCottonPurchase = new BindingSource();
bsCottonPurchase.DataSource = ds.Tables["cottonpurchase"];

// bind the grid            
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsCottonPurchase;

// And bind the TextBoxes
this.TxtSlipNo.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsCottonPurchase, "slipNo");

enableDisableControls(false);
```

this is done under load of my form

Comment: Could you be more specific when you say "nothing edits or nothing happens". I assume you're trying to persist the value to the database when the value changes.

Comment: yes that s exactly what i want to do. i want to beable to beable to edit / or change values and save hem in the database

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define [SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx) and call [DbDataAdapter.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at8a576f.aspx).

Comment: do i do this underload event?

Comment: You can define the UpdateCommand there, but calling Update depends on when you want the value persisted to the database. You'll also need to think about validating the users input at some point, but this is another topic.

Comment: please help me i really dont know how to go about this editting thing, cant i directly edit from my datagridview?

Comment: I am willing to help as much as I can, but you'll need to ask specific questions. I would suggest looking at the help links I provided earlier and if you have questions about that then start a new thread.

Comment: i have update and delete , all i want is a command that will let me edit/modify a value and then save it to the database. for example i have txtslipNo which value is lets say 4 and its already saved in the database, now what if the user want to replace that 4 for something else? how can i edit the value?

Comment: Add a button to your form and register to its click event. Inside that event handler call DbDataAdapter.Update passing in your DataSet. I would also recommend passing in DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged as the last parameter in the call this.TxtSlipNo.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsCottonPurchase, "slipNo").

Comment: hi tim Smojver plsease could u could u give me the coding i really dont know how to go about it :( thank you

Comment: I would recommend hiring a consultant who can discuss the entire project scope and possibly uncover any unmet needs you may not be aware of.